# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: // error while executing this

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
                WebDriver driver ;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        driver = new ChromeDriver (options);
        driver.get("https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/");
        
        
        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(sUsername);
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(sPassword);
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
```

i'm trying to executing this in selenium. its showing the error as above

Comment: There is insufficient information to diagnose the problem ... except to say that you need to find and fix the compilation error before you attempt to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation errors are in the below 2 lines

```
driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(sUsername);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(sPassword);
```

I see 2 variables `sUsername` and `sPassword` which have not been declared and initiated in your code.

**Solution:**

1. Either remove the variable and pass the String directly as following

```
driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("<Enter the actual username here>");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("<Enter actual pwd here>");
```

2. Or declare and initialise these 2 variables as below:

```
String sUsername = "Your actual username here";
String sPassword = "Your acutal password here";
driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(sUsername);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(sPassword);
```

**NOTE:** Despite this if it still gives compilation errors, that means the issue is somewhere else in the other part of the code which you have not shared in the question.

Comment: This is one possibility for the compilation error.  Other possibilities include missing imports, checked exceptions not being caught, and so on.

Comment: @StephenC - Agree with you. Updated the answer mentioning same in the Note.